# How to write rules in webpack for fonts with reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I got error when I try to start my react project with webpack. I think I've covered rules for fonts in my webpack but when I tried to run the app I get an error. I'm new to react and webpack.

This is my webpack config:

```
var config = {
  entry:'./src/index.js',
  output:{
    path:'./',
    filename:'driven.js'
  },
  module:{
    loaders: [
      {
     test: /\.jsx?$/,
     loader: 'babel',
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     query: {
       presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
     }
   },
   {
     test: /\.css$/,
     loaders: ['style', 'css']
   },
   {
     test: /\.png$/,
     loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
   },
   {
     test: /\.jpg$/,
     loader: "file-loader"
   },
   {
     test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
   },
   {
     test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
   },
   {
     test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: 'file'
   },
   {
     test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
   },
   {
     test: /\.gif$/i,
     loaders: [
       'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
       'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
     ]
   },
   {
     test: /\.json?$/,
     loader: 'json'
   }
    ]

    }
  }

module.exports = config;
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/icomoon.eot?uwh3dg
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\icomoon.eot?uwh3dg Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.parse (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:515:10)
    at Object.parse (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:6028-6065 6:6088-6125

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/icomoon.ttf?uwh3dg
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\icomoon.ttf?uwh3dg Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.parse (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:515:10)
    at Object.parse (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:6174-6211

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Light.otf
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\SFUIDisplay-Light.otf Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:1414-1454

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Semibold.otf
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\SFUIDisplay-Semibold.otf Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:1987-2030

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Regular.otf
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\SFUIDisplay-Regular.otf Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:1697-1739

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Medium.otf
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\SFUIDisplay-Medium.otf Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:2278-2319

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/icomoon.woff?uwh3dg
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\icomoon.woff?uwh3dg Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:6245-6283

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/icomoon.svg?uwh3dg
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\icomoon.svg?uwh3dg Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:727:47)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:6313-6350

ERROR in ./src/common_assets/css/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Bold.otf
Module parse failed: D:\jasmel\react\lp\src\common_assets\css\fonts\SFUIDisplay-Bold.otf Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\jasmel\react\lp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/common_assets/css/style.css 6:2561-2600
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple:

your regular expression test `/\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/`  dose not match with your file name `icomoon.eot?uwh3dg` so thats why webpack dont know witch loader to apply on this file

to fix this write a regular expression so that it match with your filename or keep your filename so that it matches with your regular expression. for testing your Regex you can use this site [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The file-loader isn't matching the font url due to the passed arguments, ?v=4.4.0, at the end.

I use the following to catch the any passed arguments, notice the (?.*$|$) instead of a plain $

```
test: /\.(jpe|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
```

this is for all types,, you can seperate the same for seperate rules,for example

for **.eot** files you can write

```
test: /\.eot(\?.*$|$)/,
```

Hope this will help others